# Android ConstraintLayout how do i reuse layout and still constrain the layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am struggling to get ConstraintLayout to work for me when I want to refactor common layout code into a separate xml file.  I can easily do this with RelativeLayouts but I believe RelativeLayouts are deprecated and we should be using ConstraintLayous now.

I have an app with a screen which has a different layout on portrait and landscape as illustrated in the diagram below.

[image]

I have 2 layout files with the same name ("my_layout.xml"), one in "layout" folder and one in "layout-land".  Currently i have duplicated all the xml in both the layout files and adjusted the constraints so that in the landscape version the views are placed horizontally.

Portrait version

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 1 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 2 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottom="@+id/OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar" />


    <!-- SCROLL BAR VIEWS -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/slow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fast"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintStartEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 3 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Landscape version

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 1 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 2 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottom="@+id/OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


    <!-- SCROLL BAR VIEWS -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/OtherViews2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/slow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fast"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintStartEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 3 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/OtherViews2""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The xml for the "Slow" textbox, the scrollbar and the "Fast" textbox is duplicated in both files. I would like to move the layout for these 3 elements into a separate file and reference it in both "my_layout.xml" files so its more reusable and no duplication across layout files.  I want to keep my hierarchy flat (otherwise i would just use RelativeLayouts).  I do not know how to specify the constraints of the new reusable xml layout file for the scrollbar UI.

Portrait version reusing the scrollbar layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 1 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 2 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottom="@+id/OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/scrollbar
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"       />


    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 3 -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Reusable scrollbar layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <!-- SCROLL BAR VIEWS -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>         ****************** 
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews3" ****************** 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/slow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fast"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintStartEnd_toEndOf="parent" />       ****************** 

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I do not know what to put for the lines marked with ****. If I specify that the "slow" textbox starts at the start of the parent, that will not work for the landscape version. I would like this scrollbar layout to just indicate the slow is to the left, the scrollbar in the middle (taking up all remaining space) and the fast textbox is on the right.  **How do i do that using Constraint Layout?**  **Also how do i center all 3 views vertically?**

RelativeLayout is so much easier, as i would say the slow textbox is alignedParentLeft, the fast is alignedParentRight and the scrollbar is to the right of the slow textbox and to the left of the fast textbox.  Finally i would say all 3 views are centered vertically in the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view in the included layout cannot refer to a view in the layout file in which it is included. You can still use an included layout with a different approach.

Look at the included layout with the fast/slow text and the seek bar as a self-enclosed entity - something like the following:

**scrollbar.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Slow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/slow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fast"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/slow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/slow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fast"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can now include this layout in layouts for portrait and landscape orientation:

**activity_main.xml (portrait)**

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OtherViews2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottom="@+id/OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="4" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/scrollbar"
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OtherViews2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OtherViews3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml (landscape)**

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews2"
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OtherViews2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottom="@+id/OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/OtherViews1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="8" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
        layout="@layout/scrollbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/OtherViews3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/OtherViews3" />

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS 3 -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OtherViews3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OtherViews3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/OtherViews2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/OtherViews2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The included layout file can be treated, in terms of constraints and size, like its own widget. See [*Re-using layouts with <include/>*](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I thought adding start/end = parent in the scrollbar would have taken effect when included in another view.  Thankfully it doesn't and I can put the alignments on the include statement.

There is one minor mistake in your answer. You have 'layout_height="0dp"' in the portrait version whereas it should be "wrap_content"

Comment: The other thing i noticed, if you do not include "layout_width" and "layout_height" on the "include" tag, the constraints are ignored.  You need to have these 2 tags on every element in a constraint layout (either directly or via a style)